# How to run a script every Monday morning on my express.js website (or any other specific time)?

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I'd like to be able to run 'node sendSomeEmails.js' once every Monday morning.

So far, the easiest way I've found to do it, is actually stick a reminder in my calendar and spin up a terminal and do it myself : (

I'm building an automated email series using Mandrill. Users will subscribe on my website (built on node.js with express), get the first email right away, and then every Monday morning after that I'd like to send the next email in the series. I'll maintain how far along each subscribers is in my database, but I don't know the best way to trigger the Monday morning sends.

I'm running my site on IBM Bluemix, by the way. Maybe there's an easy way to do this with AWS... Although, nothing's ever been easy for me on AWS.

Comment: See [this thread](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/7769/how-can-we-add-a-cron-job-in-bluemix.html) for some hints on how to set up what is effectively a "cron job" in Bluemix.

Comment: There's also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188580/workload-scheduler-for-node-js-script-is-it-equivalent-to-cron-jobs-in-bluemix). Maybe I'm just naive, but I kinda wish I could just ask Bluemix or some services on Bluemix to run node automatedEmail.js on Mondays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this but it looks possible based on there API.

Mandrill supports message scheduling. It also supports webhooks, you should schedule an email, and setup a webhook.  Then when the message is sent it will trigger the webhook to schedule the next email.

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582667-Can-I-schedule-a-message-to-send-at-a-specific-time-

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/webhooks.JSON.html

Comment: Thanks! Cool idea! I could also just schedule everything up front and skip the webhook, but I think this still falls a little short. If for instance I wanted to add an email midway through the email series, I'd have to application code instead of just a single line in my database. Plus is costs money to hold things in schedule : (

Comment: I see your point.  Have you considered using heroku's free tier cron scheduler or app engine to run once a week and hit a url on your Bluemix server?

Comment: Not a bad idea. I've never used Heroku, guess I could start.

Comment: Bluemix seems to have something similar: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/WorkloadScheduler/index.html#unique_850144815